# life of an object created with copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I use c++. Suppose I write the following code:

```
struct node
{
    int sum;
    int min;
};

vector<node> arrnode;

for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
     node n1;

     n1.sum=0;
     n1.min=0;
     arrnode.push_back(n1);
}
```

I know that n1 is a local variable and its destroyer is called when I move from **xth**  to 
**(x+1)th** count of 'j' in the *for* loop.But what about the object which is made by invoking copy constructor of *n1* and is inserted into the vector *arrnode*. Will it be destroyed only when *arrnode* is destroyed?

Comment: Incidentally, your whole declaration + loop can be written *in one statement*: `vector<node> arrnode(n, {0, 0});`. (Also, it’s not “destroyer”, it’s “destructor”.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it be destroyed only when arrnode is destroyed?

YES. `std::vector` implements [RAII idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), all elements of **arrnode** will be destroyed when **arrnode** goes out of scope.

If you just want to initialize `arrnode` with same value, simply construct it by:

```
vector<node> arrnode{n, {0,0}};
```

If you want to initialize with different value:

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
   arrnode.push_back({j,j});
}
```

This will make code cleaner and quicker.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it be destroyed only when arrnode is destroyed?

Yes. That is exactly the point of `std::vector` (and all other containers in the Standard Library) which destroys the elements it contains when container itself gets destructed.